# Can I link to other question without commenting or answering?

Tags: support, stack-exchange, linked-questions

Reading a question X, I see that another question Y either answers the question or has useful information.

I could add a comment or an answer to question X saying "you should look at Y", which will add question Y to the "Linked" section of question X.

Is there any way to simply link question Y to question X without having to make a comment or answer?

Is there any way to link multiple similar questions together, even when Stack's automatic "similar questions" feature doesn't work, especially if the linked questions are on different subsites?

Comment: If you really want someone to see it, you should comment... Personally, I never look at the related questions list, so unless it's in a comment or answer, I won't see it... and if another question answers the question, you should mark it as a duplicate.

Comment: @Catija Even if the duplicate question is on another subsite?

Comment: There's no formal mechanism for cross-site linking afaik, so I'd just leave a comment or suggest an edit.

Comment: You can't mark as a dupe if it's on another site... but a comment would still work just fine.  And, if it's on-topic on the site you're currently on, then there's no reason to move it.

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no way to add something directly to the linked section. I do however think this makes sense, because the linked section is about questions that were actually linked unlike 'related' which is just stuff that might be valuable to look at. Honestly, if you wish to tell the OP to check out another question, then that's *exactly* what comments are for. The linked section is mostly only useful to check whether somebody else already mentioned something you're thinking of.