# Can we have an efficient official method to link Similar Questions without resorting to comments

Tags: feature-request, comments

I've been having some discussions with a few individuals with regards to the [role of comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work) on this site, and one of the important factors is the temporary nature of comments ("Comments are temporary 'Post-It' notes left on a question or answer"). Three of the purposes of comments are clearly temporary in nature:

- Clarification comments can be deleted once the original post is edited to include clarification (preferably with a suitable explanation for the edit in the Edit Summary) or enough time has passed that it is clear it won't be.
- Constructive criticism can be deleted once the criticism is either incorporated or rejected by the original poster (a suitable passage of time can qualify as rejection of criticism).
- Transient information such as an "alert ... that the question has been updated" is intrinsically transient and can obviously be deleted once enough time has been provided for the original poster to become aware of the information.

However, another type of comment is not so easily justified as temporary: **"relevant but minor ... information."** Some of these relevant commentary can be included in the post through an edit or included in an answer, but one common type of edit in this category is linking to a similar/related question. Having a framework to provide these links outside of the comments would go a long way to improving the usefulness of those links (since comments are intended to be temporary).

Other solutions considered:

- Including the links in the question itself

  - This fails since sometimes the questions are not necessary for understanding the question-asker's confusion, and can simply lead to an increased difficulty in deciphering the actual problem that needs to be solved.
- Incorporating similar questions in answers

  - Similarly, similar questions may provide greater confusion if they are only peripherally related. Additionally, someone may want to provide a similar/related question, but does not have enough expertise to adequately answer.
- Leaving them in comments

  - While this certainly works, it seems to go against the goal of comments as transient. Additionally, an official module for related questions would help keep the site looking neater.

---

It seems like there is already an effective framework for this mechanic in the duplicate questions system. A similar voting system, that places the similar/related questions in a different location would work wonders.

Here's an example of how this could be implemented to be non-intrusive and functional:

Here is how a duplicate question appears:

[image]

As you can see, a similar question exists within the question itself. Here is how a question incorporating my vision for this system might look:

[image]

---

(for irony's sake)

### Related Questions:

[Can I link to other question without commenting or answering?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/264064/can-i-link-to-other-question-without-commenting-or-answering)

Comment: In your example, did you intend to remove the duplicate banner at the top? Is this designed to appear only before it's actually closed as a duplicate? Right now the banner seems to be a bit overly-obvious since there are two of them.

Comment: @Catija All I did was add the "Similar Questions" banner (which was my suggestion) in the stead of the link in the question body. Everything else is the same as in the original question.

Comment: But that's not the original question. That banner that is at the top of the question isn't part of the question. It's a duplicate close redirect created by the system. It's already doing what you want... for closed questions. In the case of a question that's *open* (or in the process of being closed as a duplicate) that's different and this seems like an interesting idea.

Comment: @Catija The closed question is also linking to a *Similar Question* that is not the same as the duplicate link. I would like an open qusetion to be linkable too, but I used an example that also had a duplicate-link to show how simple this change would be to implement

Comment: But mods can add more links to that duplicate close if there are more than one... and we already link similar questions in the sidebar.

Comment: @Catija [We cannot link similar questions in the sidebar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/264064/can-i-link-to-other-question-without-commenting-or-answering). The system just jumps all links in question body, comments, or answer bodies into the sidebar automatically. But the links I'm describing don't necessarily fit in those locations

Comment: The problem I see with this is the area underneath the question is going to get really crowded real fast. Russian speakers [already see an extra banner on some Stack Overflow questions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJoWX.png), pointing them to actual duplicates on the Russian site. IMHO, the sidebar is the place for related questions.

Comment: If "*sometimes the questions are not necessary for understanding the question-asker's confusion, and can simply lead to an increased difficulty in deciphering the actual problem that needs to be solved*", then calling greater attention to related questions in a banner seems like it'd make this problem *worse*. If there's no such issue with a related question, what's wrong with putting it as a footnote to the question, exactly as your example did?  Or, perhaps, with a little formatting work, something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qEzwD.png) ?